# Clojure: Is it possible to Return A Function Parameter without Parenthesis?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn foo                       ;Assume the user types: (foo '(John))

 [input]

 (cond
(some #{'John}? input) RETURN JOHN HERE, NOT (JOHN)
)
```

I simply want to return the input which is John. But the John with parenthesis is returned if I do (input) after the cond statement. How can I return only John. I realize it is possible to return things such as false, true, but Clojure does not like returning other things.

Comment: This question looks very very similar to the string of questions recently asked by [noobprogrammer99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12358384/noobprogrammer99). Are you the same person? If so, please keep your questions under a single identity.

Answer (score 3):

If your `input` is a sequence of symbols, `(some #{'John} input)` will return `John` on its own, not `(John)`:

```
user=> (some #{'John} '(Sam Dave John Fred))
John
```

Perhaps you just don't need to wrap this up in `cond`?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to take the first item of the passed list, then you can use the `first` function, e.g. `(first input)`.

For example:

```
user=> (def input '(John))
#'user/input
user=> input
(John)
user=> (def output (first input))
#'user/output
user=> output
John
```

Double check that you need your input in this form though, if there is a way to use strings instead of symbols, a lot becomes simpler.